# creation of multiple index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I was reading the document and happened to read the multiple index creation and ability to search on multiple indexes and also its possible to search specific search in Elasticsearch.

For example i have two index like releasedArea and WorkArea. am i can search by giving 
http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true which will search in all index

and i can specifically search like
http://localhost:9200/releasedArea,WorkArea/_search?pretty=true.

So i think this specification will improve in terms of performance, if already knows where to search. if we don't know, where to search it should search in all index.

Could you please tell me, am i correct? else please let me know, what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. If you do not provide any index name, then it will search in all indices and of course this might hit search performance. If you know which index to search, you should specify it explicitly while using [Search APIs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html).

Comment: Thanks But how about the searching specified by type In single index, in terms of performance. If specified type will it search on that specific type in that index. How do in terms of performance

Comment: Of course. If you also specify the type explicitly, search operation would be restricted to potentially lesser number of documents and hence performance would be better.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like, indexing in elasticsearch is dependent on type document. And it's not spread across all documents